# NSMutableArray with tableview source data modified in multiple threads, how to avoid blocking while configuring the cell

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, thread-safety, grand-central-dispatch

I have a `NSMutaleArray` that contains instances of class X.  The tableView cell at row `i` is populated using contents of array at index `i`.

The contents of the array are created based on incoming JSON data from the network.  So, I have a helper function that converts JSON data into these objects and stores them in the array.  The object may be modified after storing in the array (for instance image belonging to cell gets downloaded and file pointer is added to the object).

Currently, I am making the reads and writes thread safe putting them inside dispatch_sync & dispatch_barrier_async.  Some issues I see

1. To create the tableview cell I need to do a read.  This is also going through the dispatch_sync.  Hence, it looks like there is chance of it getting blocked because data for a non-visible but close enough cell is being updated.  Any best practices to avoid this?
2. Is there some smart way for the block submitted through  dispatch_sync and disaptch_barrier_sync to only wait if another block is either modifying, removing the same index of the NSMUtableArray or value associated withs are key of NSMUtableDictionary?
3. To make the code more readable, I am thinking of sub-classing NSMutableArray and creating a THreadSafeMutableArray class that over-rides the objectForIndex and subscript methods. Any issues with this approach?

Answer (score 0):

Your NSMutableArray should be an atomic property (the default value is this) maybe you changed to nonatomic in the declaration.
Look the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html

Apple documentation:

> This means that the synthesized accessors ensure that a value is always fully retrieved by the getter method or fully set via the setter method, even if the accessors are called simultaneously from different threads.

```
@interface XYZObject : NSObject
@property NSObject *implicitAtomicObject;          // atomic by default
@property (atomic) NSObject *explicitAtomicObject; // explicitly marked atomic
@end
```